# How to add application version to Inno Setup startup message?

Tags: inno-setup

With Inno Setup, if we choose to keep the prompt dialog (`DisableStartupPrompt=False`) the displayed message is managed by the localization file with the reference `SetupLdrStartupMessage`. For instance in English locale file:

```
SetupLdrStartupMessage=This will install %1. Do you wish to continue?
```

By default the setup will replace `%1` by the name of the application defined by the variable `AppName`. How to make the text display `AppVerName` instead ?

I would like to get the following text :

> This will install MyApplicationName 4.1. Do you wish to continue?

The Pascal function `InitializeSetup()` is not a correct option for me for two reasons:

1. This section is called after the language selection, called itself after the startup prompt. I want to keep this first popup.
2. It imply to re-write as many custom message as language you manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the version be part of the message:

```
#define MyAppVer "4.1"

[Setup]
AppName=MyApplicationName
AppVersion={#MyAppVer}

[Messages]
SetupLdrStartupMessage=This will install %1 {#MyAppVer}. Do you wish to continue?
```

Comment: Many many thanks, simple & smart solution ! I never paid attention to the difference between sections `Messages` & `CustomMessages`. And to satisfy the multilingual requirements I did the following:
`english.SetupLdrStartupMessage=....
french.SetupLdrStartupMessage=....
italian.SetupLdrStartupMessage=....
`